# Cannot convert from *const to & in += operator

Tags: c++

I was staring at this all night before I decided to give up and go to sleep - a few hours into it again today, I still don't have it. I am unable to figure out how to change the `const`-ness and parameters to correctly return (on the operator+=). Any help?

The error pops up at the `return this` statement in the `operator+=` overload.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class Matrix {
private:
    unsigned rows, cols;

public:
    Matrix();
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols);

    std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix;
    Matrix<T>& operator=(Matrix<T> rhs);

    //Matrix mathematical operations                                                                                                                                                                                               
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix<T>& operator+=(const Matrix<T>& rhs);

    // Access the individual elements                                                                                                                                                                                               
    T& operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col);
    const T& operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col) const;

    // Access the row and column sizes                                                                                                                                                                                              
    unsigned get_rows() const;
    unsigned get_cols() const;

    void swap(Matrix<T>& rhs);
};

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() {}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {}

// Parameter Constructor                                                                                                                                                      
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols) {

    matrix.resize(_rows);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
        matrix[i].resize(_cols, 1); // change back to 0 after debug

    rows = _rows;
    cols = _cols;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix<T> rhs) {
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {
    Matrix<T> result(*this);
    result += rhs;
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator+=(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            this->matrix[i][j] += rhs(i, j);
        }
    }

    return this; // error pops up here
}

// Access the individual elements                                                                                                                                             
template<typename T>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col) {
    return this->matrix[row][col];
}

// Access the individual elements (const)                                                                                                                                     
template<typename T>
const T& Matrix<T>::operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col) const{
    return this->matrix[row][col];
}

// Get the number of rows of the matrix                                                                                                                                       
template<typename T>
unsigned Matrix<T>::get_rows() const {
    return this->rows;
}

//Get the number of columns of the matrix                                                                                                                                    
template<typename T>
unsigned Matrix<T>::get_cols() const {
    return this->cols;
}

template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::swap(Matrix<T>& rhs) {
    using std::swap;

    swap(this->rows, rhs.rows);
    swap(this->cols, rhs.cols);
    swap(this->matrix, rhs.matrix);
}


// for debugging
template<typename T>
void print_matrix(Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_rows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.get_cols(); j++) {
            std::cout << matrix(i, j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Matrix<double> matrix1(5, 5);
    Matrix<double> matrix2(5, 5);

    // Start testing
    Matrix<double> matrix3 = matrix1 + matrix2;
    print_matrix(matrix1);

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you running into problems?

Comment: @mogambo Line 88 - the end of the += operator. Realized I made the mistake of not putting that in and am adding it to the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `+=` operator, you probably want:

```
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator+=(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {
    //....
    return *this;
          //^^
}
```

The linker error is because you did not define:

```
Matrix(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
```

Comment: Creates a weird linking error I've been getting (single file as above - no others in the project) but took care of the error!